# How to determine the last part of URL with jq?

Tags: jq

I have to distinguish between the following two paths.

shorter: `https://www.example.com/`
longer: `https://www.example.com/foo/`

In Bash script, using Bash built-in literals as follows returns only longer one.

```
$ url1=https://www.example.com/
$ url2=https://www.example.com/foo/

$ cut -d/ -f4 <<<${url1%/*}   # this returns nothing
>$

$ cut -d/ -f4 <<<${url2%/*}   # this returns last part of path
>$ foo
```

So it could be identified longer one in Bash script,
but now I have to define same filter for JSON value handled in jq.

If jq can write like the following,  my goal can be achieved...

`jq '. | select( .url | (cut -d/ -f4 <<< ${url2%/*})!=null) )'`

But can not do that. How can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jq has many string-handling functions -- one could do worse than checking the jq [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).  For the task at hand, using a regex function would probably be best, but since you mentioned `cut -d/ -f4`, it might be of interest to note that much the same effect can be achieved by:

```
split("/")[3]
```

For the last non-trivial part you could consider:

```
sub("/ *$";"") | split("/")[-1]
```

Comment: What a simple but accurate function. I will re-read the manual. Thank you.